# I have an error when using pst-func package

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot, auto-pst-pdf

when i use pspicture* to draw a chart this error occurs but plotted.
file:framed.sty  error:no room for a new \dimen.[image]

Comment: Could we have a minimal (non)working example?

Answer (score 2):

Put into your preamble:

```
\documentclass{...}
\usepackage{etex}
```

Comment: Is it possible a short description about the package etex?!!

Comment: see http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-noroom.html